# Justification of definition 2.7.1 (Potential cause) in Causality by Pearl

Tags: causality, graphical-model, bayesian-network, causal-diagram

In *Causality - Models, Reasoning And Inference* by *Pearl*, **definition 2.7.1** says -

> **Potential Cause definition:**
>  
> A variable $X$ has a potential causal influence on another variable $Y$ (that is inferable from $\hat {P}$) if the following conditions hold -
> 1. $X$ and $Y$ are dependent in every context.
> 2. There exists a variable $Z$ and a context $S$ such that
>      (i) $X$ and $Z$ are independent given $S$ (i.e., $X \perp Z|S$) and
>      (ii) $Z$ and $Y$ are dependent given $S$

I want to understand how the second condition (with its two sub-conditions) forms a defining factor for potential causes.

**Note:** I know the $IC^*$ algorithm (as given in Section 2.6) and also understand the logic behind rules $R_1$ and $R_2$ for aligning the arrowheads. I have a feeling that these rules might be the inspiration behind the definition, but am unable to figure that out.
Hence, it is fine if the answer is provided in this context.

Comment: Maybe it helps to share my own confusion: 
It seems that in all subfigures of Figure 2.4 there is a path from the potential causes $b$ and $c$ to their effect $d$. 
However, if I see correctly, 2.7.1 should still be fulfilled for $b$ and $c$ even if $a$ did not exist in the graph (one could use $S=\emptyset$), which would mean this need not be the case.
If this were correct, I could make the genuine cause $d \to e$ a potential cause by adding a new node $f$ with the sole edge $f \to e$ to the graph. This does not seem right...